# Issue in JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
  <p id="message"></p>
  <script src="forloops.js"></script>
</body>
```

The javascipt for loop code is:

```
var msg=document.getElementById("message");
var num=Number(prompt("enter your number"));
var output=0;

//loop

for (var i=0;i<= num ;i++ ){
    output= "number is " +i;
}

//output
msg.textContent=output;
```

There is only single output even when i give the num value more than 1.
What are the improvements needs to be made in order to make this code for work ?

Comment: Could you please sum up the problem in the title instead of just saying that you need help?

Comment: You didn't specify what is the desired behavior. But perhaps you meant to prompt the user inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to append to the output rather than overwrite it inside your `for` loop. Try using `+=` instead, e.g.,

```
for (var i=0;i<= num ;i++ ){
    output+= "number is " +i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you just need to make small change.

```
var msg=document.getElementById("message");
var num=Number(prompt("enter your number"));
var output='';

for (var i=0;i<= num ;i++ ){
   output += "number is " +i+"/";
}
msg.textContent=output;
```